# How to center a box that varies width inside a box with fixed width?

Tags: css

I am working on a website: http://felipewarrener.55freehost.com

As you can see there is a content slider, I've added media queries to make the text smaller and the boxes scale in width (I will eventually make the text small enough so that it wont make the boxes bigger than the containter div.

However, I don't know how I can vertically center these boxes? When I scale it down they will need to be vertically centered or else they will just float down.

They are positioned relatively as i felt that was the best option

Could anyone suggest or tell me what method I should use?

Thanks for taking the time to read

Felipe

Comment: Google is where this question should be asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use flex

```css
.container { 
display: flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
align-content: center; 
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about your "A new dimension to colouring PVC", 
What you *could* do is have the header container be `relative`ly positioned, and then give your text this class:

```
.vert-centered{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Pretty sure your text is floating down to prevent overlap though. You might as well just hide it when the screen width gets too small.

Comment: I'm not talking about that. I'm tlaking about the black boxes inside the slider. When the screen scales down I need to vertically center them no matter what their height is

Comment: Oh, well, you could technically do the same thing to the <p> elements there. Your black box thing seems to already have ```position:relative``` so it should work